# SVN Hook with unicode output

Tags: svn, unicode, hook, locale, diacritics

I have a SVN hook which executes svnlook and sends the commit message via e-mail. When I have umlauts (ä,ü,ö or ß) in my commit message I only get "?\195?\159?\195?\182" output instead of the umlauts.

If I execute the script via shell everything is fine. If subversion executes the hook then the umlauts a scrambled. I tried to execute the mailing script from the post-commit hook using

```
LC_ALL="en_US-utf8" "$REPOS"/hooks/mailer.py "$REPOS" "$REV"
```

and inside my mailer I execute the svnlook command with

```
cmd = 'export LC_ALL="en_US-utf8" && svnlook info ' +  sys.argv[1]
```

I also set the locale environment inside my mailer.py using

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US-utf8')
```

The only error message I am getting is:

```
svnlook: warning: cannot set LC_CTYPE locale
svnlook: warning: environment variable LC_ALL is en_US-utf8
svnlook: warning: please check that your locale name is correct
```

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3):

1. Your problem has <strike>two</strike>three faces

   - Can your hook get Unicode data (and does it receive log-message in unmodified form)
   - How your mailer sends this Unicode
   - Can your MUA show non-ASCII e-mail's body (**properly prepared** by mailer)

Some needed steps for getting answers in the order of questions above

1. For testing in hook replace mailing of data by storing in file, check content by viewer, which can render Unicode text (and check, that text really is UTF8, for umlauts it can be some of windows-* charsets)
2. If you get readable text in p.1, you must to check headers (in your MUA) of previously received notification and inspect `Content-Type` (`charset=` part, mime-type is irrelevant here) and (optional) `Content-Transfer-Encoding`. I *assume and suspect* that the charset **definition** does not match with the **actual state** (us-ascii vs UTF8) and in this case MTA and MUA may give described by you result. I don't know, can you redefine message-headers in your mailer.py, but you **must** create mail message with correct header Content-Type
3. When you will be able to generate e-mails with `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF8`, test your MUA for processing UTF8-encoded emails (can be moved to p.0 as independent from previous results test)

PS: This question must to be addressed to ServerFault: it's mostly postmaster's area of problem, and you have more chances to see real postmasters (and get full detailed answers instead of my synopsis) on SF

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this the following line to your hook script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Had the same problem, this worked for me.